# visual studio code unable to debug - Target debugging is no longer supported with the legacy driver

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-code

I am using visual studio code for a c++ cmake project.

I am unable to use cmake: target debug (CTRL + F5)

When debugging the project I get

> Target debugging is no longer supported with the legacy driver

**Platform and Versions**

```
Visual studio code 1.28.2
C/C++ 0.20.1
CMake 0.0.17
CMake Tools 1.1.2 (vector of bool)
CMake Tools Helper 0.2.1
Doxygen Documentation Generator 0.4.1
Include Autocomplete 0.0.4
Python 2018.9.2
Swig(.tpl) 0.0.6
Compiler/Toolchain: GCC 5.4.0
```

Has anybody encountered this?

Comment: a quick google turns up https://github.com/vector-of-bool/vscode-cmake-tools/issues/388

Comment: I tried that. I have the latest of everything. although cmake version is 0.0.17 (latest) which doesn't match?

Comment: what is your version of cmake?

Comment: In visual studio code extension it is 0.0.17.

Comment: in linux it is cmake 3.5.1.

Comment: You need a newer version of cmake, from the link I posted "CMake versions (< 3.7.2) is no longer supported"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The visual studio code cmake extension requires CMake 3.7.2 or newer. See https://github.com/vector-of-bool/vscode-cmake-tools/issues/388

If this isn't available from your package manager you will need to download it from https://cmake.org/